# check if list has one or two layers of sublists

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a easy way to see if a sublist of a list contains another sublist or not. If it has one i want a = 1, if it has two layers i want a = 0. What i tried so far:

```
newElemLines = [[1, 42], [2, 42]]

try:
    newElemLines[0][0][0]
    a = 1
except ValueError:
    a = 0
```

newElemLines could also look like in the following example, which should result in a = 1

```
newElemLines = [[[1, 42], [2, 42]], [[1, 42], [2, 42]]]
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Can someone help me?
Edit: It is enough to check the zeroeth element.

Comment: If the nesting is *regular* this is relatively straightforward. If it is *arbitrary* then that complicates things a bit.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are guaranteed that each element of `a` is already a list, and if *any* of those lists contain a sublist as *at least one* element, `a=1`? E.g., `[[1, 2], [3, [4, 5]]]` will result in a 1?

Comment: Also, how does the example you posted not work? (Beyond the obvious syntax error showing that you did not test it)

Comment: @MadPhysicist It says TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable when      newElemLines = [[1, 42], [2, 42]]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is regular

Comment: A simple list comprehension, `a = [1 if type(b) == list else 0 for a in newElemLines for b in a]`

Answer (score 0):

Hm, here's a quick general solution I cooked up. It seems to work but my sense is that there are edge-cases I haven't considered. But it's  start.

```
In [10]: def how_deep(lst, level=0):
    ...:     if isinstance(lst, list):
    ...:         return max(how_deep(l, level+1) for l in lst)
    ...:     return level - 1
    ...:

In [11]: how_deep([1,2])
Out[11]: 0

In [12]: how_deep([[1, 42], [2, 42]])
Out[12]: 1

In [13]: how_deep([[[[1],[2]],[3],[4],5],6,7,[8,[[[[[10]]]]]]])
Out[13]: 6
```